# Pass extra argument to async map

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Signature for async.map is map(arr, iterator, callback) (https://github.com/caolan/async#map)

I have a `var context //object`
and I need to pass this to the iterator. How do i do this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use bind, in two ways:

```
iterator.bind(context)
```

This will make `context` available within the iterator function as `this`.

The other method is to create a partial function:

```
iterator.bind(null, context)
```

This will make `context` available as the first argument to the iterator function. So instead of the iterator signature being `iterator(item, callback)`, it becomes `iterator(context, item, callback)`.

Simple demo:

```
// first:
async.map([1, 2, 3], function(item, callback) {
  callback(null, item * this.mult);
}.bind({ mult: 5 }), function(err, results) {
  console.log('R', results);
});

// second:
async.map([1, 2, 3], function(ctx, item, callback) {
  callback(null, item * ctx.mult);
}.bind(null, { mult: 5 }), function(err, results) {
  console.log('R', results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. will try iterator.bind(null, context), as I need "item" also.

Comment: @user644745 The `item` will still be passed to `iterator` when it's called by `async.map()`. The `.bind()` just sets up `context` as an extra argument before the `item`.

Comment: this is great...a little strange but nice lesson on language features

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. How can I append the extra argument, instead of making it the first argument?

Comment: @Abimbola for that you can use something like Lodash's [`partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight)

Answer (score 0):

With arrow functions you can curry your functions and pass in extra parameters:

```
async.map([1,2,3], context => (item, callback) => {
  // you now have access to context, item, and callback here
}, (err, results)=>{
  // async.map callback function
});
```

I like to put my functions outside the async functions to keep things clean:

```
const processItem = context => (item, callback) => {
  // process items here
};

async.map([1,2,3], processItem(context)(item, callback), (err, results)=>{
  // async.map callback function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With arrow functions the best practice is to use async.apply.
async.apply provide the ability for adding extra parameters, which will be passed to the target function as first parameters. Here is an example code:

```
processItemFuction(context, item, callback) {
    //Here you can access context as well
}

async.map([1,2,3]), async.apply(processItemFuction, context), (err, res) {
    // async.map callback function
}
```